# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent Events

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel Model Events. My requirement is to pass additional parameters to event.

I am trying like that:

```
$feedback = new Feedback();
    $feedback->user_id = $this->user_id;
    $feedback->feedback = $request->feedback;
    $data = array(
        'message' => $request->feedback,
        'from' => $this->data->user->email,
        'name' => $this->data->user->displayname
    );
    $feedback->save($data);
```

My event is:

```
public function boot()
{
    Feedback::saved(function ($item) {
        //\Event::fire(new SendEmail($item));
    });
}
```

But it only send Model object while i am trying to sending:

```
$data = array(
        'message' => $request->feedback,
        'from' => $this->data->user->email,
        'name' => $this->data->user->displayname
    );
```

How i send this to event?

Comment: dd($item) see what you get there?

Comment: Are `message`, `from` and `name` going to be attributes of the model?

Comment: @BasheerAhmed dd($items) returns model object not the data that i pass in  `$feedback->save($data);`

Comment: @svrnm No these are not the attributes of the model. I want to send extra parameters and these are the extra parameters.

Comment: You can't pass data using the `save` method...

Comment: @svrnm So any other way i can pass data to `created` or `Saved` callbacks

Comment: No, not as function parameter.

Answer (score 2):

There definitely are ways around this problem. The first one that comes to mind is getting the `Auth` data inside the `Provider` where your event lives.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
use Auth; //Assuming this is how you are handling authentication

public function boot()
{
    Feedback::saved(function ($item) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $data = [ 
            'message' => $item->feedback, 
            'from' => $user->email, 
            'name' => $user->displayname
        ];
        \Event::fire(new SendEmail($data));
    });
}
```

You may be able to do `$item->user->email` instead, and not bother with Auth, I'm just not able to know the relationships from what you've posted so far.

The code might need a little adjustment to work within your application, let me know if anything else comes up!